# try sending file and string through same sockt (in java)

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer, client-server

i need to send file from server to client through some sockt (lets say port 8478) and also massage(in middel of file transfer ) (somthing like "hi", or "you reach to your limt"or "you reach to your 50% limt").

now to send only file it's easy im using 
BufferedInputStrear and BufferedOutputStream in the client and server side.
now how can i send also massage in middel of file transfer in same port (8478).

thank you all..

this how i transfer the file

server side:

```
         BufferedInputStream d=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(s));

        BufferedOutputStream outStream = new         BufferedOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream msgoutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];


        int read;
        while((read = d.read(buffer))!=-1)
        {

            //msgoutStream.writeUTF("hjlhkhjk");


            outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);

            outStream.flush();
        }
```

client side:

```
         byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        int f=0;

        while((read = d.read(buffer))!=-1)
        {
            if(ifContinun)
            {
                System.out.println("strat write to file...");
            }

        //String s1=msgInPutStream.readLine();
        //String s2=msgInPutStream.readUTF();

        outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            outStream.flush();
            if(ifContinun)
            {
                System.out.println("after write to file...");
                ifContinun=false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the file in parts.  You can invent a protocol like

```
 short stream-id
 short length of message
 bytes of the message
```

This will allow you to interleave multiple streams of data in the same socket and have the other end break up the different streams.

However, its likely to be much simpler to open two connections which avoids the need for a protocol like this. e.g. FTP does this. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to define a protocol on top of TCP. For example, the protocol can be:

1. There are a series of messages
2. Each message has a type
3. Each message is preceded by 4 bytes that carry the size of the next message
4. Each message starts with a type byte
5. The types are: 1 -- StartFile, 2 -- NextFileChunk, 3 -- TextMessage
6. The the second byte onwards contains the body of the message
7. For StartFile, the rest of the bytes constitute the filename and whatever other properties you want to send. (You can choose to use regular Java serialization.)
8. For NextFileChunk, you just have the next n bytes of the file being transferred
9. For TestMessage, the rest of the bytes would carry the text message

Comment: i edit my first post. and if i anderstad you i need to use the buffer buffer[0] for my massage? and rest of the buffer to the file info?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use some escape code to indicate when changing from file transfer to text transefer, and vice versa. Because a binary file may contain your escape codes, you must hand those some how.

But message protocol is preferable.

Comment: It can be a single byte, wihch have agreed fixed value. 
For example 0xFF. When you want to send text during file transfer: send 0xFF, then text, and 0xFF again, and after that continue file transfer.
For more information see: "Escape character" asn "Escape sequence" articles of wikipedia.